# R's do.call function unexpected behavior with mean

Tags: r, do.call

I came across an unexpected behavoiur of R's `do.call` function when combind with the `mean` function.

```
do.call(max, list(2,6,4))
6 # as expected 
do.call(min, list(2,6,4))
2 # as expected
do.call(sum, list(2,6,4))
12 # as expected
do.call(mean, list(2,6,4))
2 # should be 4!
```

What do I miss here?

Comment: Id guess it to do with the position of the `...`'s. `mean` takes the first value and the others `6,4` are swallowed up  in the dots (or other args). The other functions start with the dots, so all values are passed in to function.

Comment: try writing `mean(2, 4, 6)`

Comment: or if `do.call` is a must: `do.call(mean, list(c(2,6,4)))`